# Couldn't find 'window' in scope, Scene delegate

Tags: ios, swift

So this problem is mostly common in the `AppDelegate.swift` because of the newly added Scene delegate, but for some reason I get `couldn't find window in scope` in the scene delegate?

here is my code:

```
 func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

  if (UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ISRemember")) {
            print(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ISRemember"))
            let mainTabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "tabbar")
            window?.rootViewController = mainTabBarController
        }
        else {
            
        }
    }
```

I tried cleaning xcode's build folder but it didn't help. I also tried restarting xcode and even my mac but I still get the same error. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your scene delegate class conforms to the protocol `UIWindowSceneDelegate`. The protocol declares that there is a property named `window` of type `UIWindow`.

Since your `SceneDelegate` class is trying to conform to that protocol, you must provide that `window` property.

If you create a new iOS app project based on Swift and Storyboard, the `SceneDelegate` class will already come with the necessary declaration of `window`. If your `SceneDelegate` class doesn't have this for some reason, add this property to the class:

```
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow? // Add this line

    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
```

Comment: thank you, such a weird bug that my scene delegate didn't have the window declaration involved when I created my project